# Which one is better, making an anonymous function or making a new object

Tags: javascript, html

I want to implement undo functionality.

Now there are two ways to do this:

```
undos.push({ fn: undoFn, args: ...args });
// Usage
let { fn, args } = undos.pop();
fn(...args);
```

or:

```
undos.push(() => undoFn(...args));
// Usage
let undo = undos.pop();
undo();
```

or any other better way to implement this functionality?

Comment: What is your criteria for _better_? Seems that both are perfectly valid and reasonable approaches. The only thing I can think of is whether one of the approaches has a higher space complexity - which I would assume would be the anonymous function approach

Comment: Personally, if I understand correctly that `undos` is meant to be a collection of arbitrary undo operations, storing a function instead of an object containing the function and its arguments is far more flexible and at the same time far simpler. Consider that there may be multiple types of operations to undo and how the function abstracts any differences in handling.

Answer (score 2):

If there two ways, I would use this.

```
undos.push(() => undoFn(...args));
// Usage
let undo = undos.pop();
undo();
```

If I could detailed Information I could improve my answer.